# Is there a way to forward fill with ascending logic in pandas / numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, ffill

What is the most pandastic way to forward fill with ascending logic (without iterating over the rows)?

input:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['test'] = np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan,6,np.nan,np.nan
df['desired_output'] = np.nan,np.nan,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,6,6,6

print (df)
```

output:

```
    test  desired_output
0    NaN             NaN
1    NaN             NaN
2    1.0             1.0
3    NaN             1.0
4    NaN             1.0
5    3.0             3.0
6    NaN             3.0
7    NaN             3.0
8    2.0             3.0
9    NaN             3.0
10   6.0             6.0
11   NaN             6.0
12   NaN             6.0
```

In the 'test' column, the number of consecutive NaN's is random.

In the 'desired_output' column, trying to forward fill with ascending values only.  Also, when lower values are encountered (row 8, value = 2.0 above), they are overwritten with the current higher value.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html) to select the cumulative maximum value and [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) to replace the NaNs:

```
df['desired_output'] = df['test'].cummax().ffill()
```

output:

```
    test  desired_output
0    NaN             NaN
1    NaN             NaN
2    1.0             1.0
3    NaN             1.0
4    NaN             1.0
5    3.0             3.0
6    NaN             3.0
7    NaN             3.0
8    2.0             3.0
9    NaN             3.0
10   6.0             6.0
11   NaN             6.0
12   NaN             6.0
```

intermediate Series:

```
df['test'].cummax()

0     NaN
1     NaN
2     1.0
3     NaN
4     NaN
5     3.0
6     NaN
7     NaN
8     3.0
9     NaN
10    6.0
11    NaN
12    NaN
Name: test, dtype: float64
```